# Finding a r-atomic solution to the univariate truncated Hausdorff moment problem

Tags: pr.probability, moments

Suppose i have a certain $t>0$, and observations of moments of a random variable $X$ given by $\mu_0=1,\mu_1,...,\mu_n$.

How can i:

- Check that a measure with support $[0, \frac{1}{t}]$ with thoses $n$ first moments indeed exists
- Construct an atomic (discrete) solution $\nu(x_i) = \omega_i$ for some atoms $x_i$ and associated probabilities $\omega_i$, such that: $$\forall i \in 1,...,r, \;x_i \in [0,\frac{1}{t}] \text{ and }{\omega_i >0}, \; \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{r} \omega_i = 1$$

I found a lot of things on moment problems in general, and on the Hausdorff moment problem, but i have trouble finding the right solution to this quick problem.

Answer (score 1):

By rescaling, without loss of generality, $t=1$.
Let $c:=(c_0,\dots,c_n)$, where $c_p:=\mu_p$ (so that $c_0=1$). Let $M(c)$ denote the set of all (probability) measures $\nu$ on $[0,1]$ with moments $\int x^p\,\nu(dx)=c_p$ for all $p\in\{0,\dots,n\}$. A necessary and sufficient condition for $M(c)\ne\emptyset$ is well known; see e.g. [Karlin--Studden, Ch. IV, Theorem 1.1](https://books.google.com/books/about/Tchebycheff_systems.html?id=Rrc-AAAAIAAJ).

The set $M(c)$ of measures is compact and convex, and hence $M(c)$ has an extreme point if $M(c)\ne\emptyset$. Also, by elementary linear algebra, any extreme point of $M(c)$ is a measure supported on at most $n+1$ points. Then a solution $(x,\omega)=(x_1,\dots,x_r,\omega_1,\dots,\omega_r)$ to your problem exists for some natural $r\le n+1$.

Finding such a solution can be reduced to semidefinite optimization; see e.g. [part (c) of Proposition 3.1](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S1052623401399903).